# How do I find the drawn location of a graph in JUNG2?

Tags: java, graphing, jung

I am working with the JUNG libraries to create graphs in Java.  I need to fit a graph to its parent frame and set the view so that the graph is shown in the center of the view.

I have managed to set the zoom to the correct size using code from here:
[How to manually set the zoom on a Jung visualisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761391/how-to-manually-set-the-zoom-on-a-jung-visualisation) however the shrunken graph remains in the same place.  I have also written a function to move the graph using code from here: [How to programatically pan a VisualizationViewer with Jung (the java library)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745183/how-to-programatically-pan-a-visualizationviewer-with-jung-the-java-library).

The problem remains how do I work out how much the graph needs to be panned from its current location to center in the view.  How can I find the current location of the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the way to do this is using a **ScalingControl**.  Using the scaling control it is very easy to make sure the graph fits its parent frame, the code to do this is:

```
ScalingControl visualizationViewerScalingControl
            = new CrossoverScalingControl();

visualizationViewer.scaleToLayout(visualizationViewerScalingControl);
```

I found the way to do this by looking at the source code for the SatelliteViewDemo which also implements a SatelitteView; this allows for a zoomed out view of the graph alongside the full size version.

Comment: I don't believe this centers the graph.